# Extend a dataframe by introducing newly interpolated rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

Here is a dataframe I have:

[image]

I would like to extend this dataframe by adding more values between any neighboring rows (for brevity, I am showing only the values between 470 and 471.776):

[image]

I know that I need to apply an linear interpolator but I am not sure how to proceed.

**Note**

The first column does not always increase in units of 1; at some point in the middle of the first column, values increase in smaller increments (still larger than 0.1). However, I want to create an interpolated dataframe whose first column always increments with units of 0.1.

Comment: You can add the rows, then use `sort_values()` to get in the correct order before using interpolate

Comment: I am not sure how to do that but let me think about it.